# Android InAPP Purchase?

Tags: android

I have a Wallpaper APP, with several wallpaper. Some Wallpaper's have a price (0.2 euro).

Can I use InApp purchase to buy a wallpaper OR I can only sell my APP with InAPP Purchase?

Thanks, 
Leslie

Comment: You should definitely go for selling the wallpapers in one app. Creating an app specifically for that purpose is not that easy

Answer (score 3):

In-App Purchases are great in that they're quick and simple for the user BUT by implementing them you're tying yourself 100% to the Android Market.

This may not bother you, but many other Markets are great sources of business/income and as such I'd consider whether you wouldn't be better-off supporting the separate App purchase/download approach too.

Apart from anything else, Amazon are about to launch their own Android device (Kindle Fire) which will almost certainly be tied to their own Market only - that's a lot of customers you won't have...

Answer (score 0):

You can let user buy each wallpaper within one App, without need to create additional applications

see:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html
- [Implementing In App purchases in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022945/implementing-in-app-purchases-in-android)