# how to make a key for unlocking premium features for app

Tags: android, locking, key, unlock

I tried to implement a "pro key" for my android app to unlock features which should be locked at "trail version" (the same app without the key)...

I found some ideas and some explained code (e.g. [this](http://www.yoki.org/2010/07/31/creating-a-freepaid-app-pair-for-the-android-market/)), but if I test this stuff it wouldnt do any thing. My app doesnt recognize the "package".

The in-app-billing solution by google is much to complicated for me. I read the documentary a lot of times but it looks so weird to me. puhhh. :-/

Oh man... I spent so many days and weeks for my app and now the release is the most frustrating task to do.

I hope somebody could help me.

Best wishes from Germany
Martin

Edit:
I try to implement this in my SharedPreferences like this way:

```
if (isProInstalled(this)) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settingsactivity);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(SettingsActivity.this,
                R.xml.settingsactivity, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
            initSummary(getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i));
        }
    } else {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settingsactivity_pro);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(SettingsActivity.this,
                R.xml.settingsactivity_pro, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
            initSummary(getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make a Pro and a Non-pro edition of he app, and sell them seperatelly. The only way to do this without doing so is to enable in-app purchases and follow google's guide for in-app purchases.

Comment: It is possible with the in-app purchases feature, I'd greatly recommend the 2-Apps thought its more profitable (free app also pays you from adds) and it will be less confuzing with the google merchant,taxes from your sales ect.

Comment: okay, this will be true. :) So at this moment try the in-app-billing methode again.. importing the IInAppBillingService.aidl -> results "coulnt find .apk" ARGGGG -.- I followed every step of googles doc. oO sh**

Comment: Where do you get this error ? On Eclipse , on google dev platform?

Comment: You mean Android Studio? No, at Eclipse. This is the third time I reload my project form external storage in to eclipse. Ive never seen something complicated like that - even working with pointers in c++ is quite more comfortable than this crap. :-/ 
Do you know an good tutorial to implement in-app-billings? Did you ever implement this feature?

Comment: I believe you can easier find an awnser by submiting your question in this section of the site http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-play-services/new or by adding tag "google-play-services" because i dont really know if i can help you with this to the end as my country cant support In-App purchases.Sorry for that. (All i could find was this Q&A also on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022945/implementing-in-app-purchases-in-android)